# Spring @scheduled with cron but no overlapping crons

Tags: java, spring, cron-task

Hi I would like A cronjob to be run within spring but I also need to make sure that they don't overlap when running is this possible. Using spring boot 5.1

```
@Scheduled(cron="${con}", fixedDelay = 5000)
 public void run(){
     some method
 }
```

this obviously fails is there some way to obtain this

Comment: Yes it is, and the posted code does exactly what you expect as mentioned [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#fixedDelay--)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring non-overlapping cron, you could check whether the previous run method has finished, and if it hasn't, exit your run() function.